# Does key-value coding support declared property's custom accessor name?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, key-value-coding, accessor, declared-property

*Key-Value coding* of Cocoa makes get/set operation to properties simple. Anyway documentation says it only recognized pre-defined naming patterns. I think *Declared Property* could be supported by this feature. Actually basic access of Declared Property is just same with Key-Value coding's search pattern. The problem is custom accessor. Because the custom accessors are stored as an attribute of the property, I think it's easily possible to support them in Key-Value coding. But I can't find mention about this.

What is the regular behavior when using Key-Value coding for the Declared Properties with custom accessors?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Key-Value coding, your accessor methods must conform to specific naming conventions. In the section about (custom) accessor method names, the [Objective-C Programming Language Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW2) specifically mentions that you "should [typically] specify accessor method names that are key-value coding compliant."

For details about which names are KVC-compliant, see [Accessor Search Implementation Details](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/SearchImplementation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000955-SW1) in the Key-Value Coding Programming Guide.